# Xcode/Swift example of SOAP web services connection

Tags: swift, xcode, web-services, soap

There are several versions of a temperature conversion webservices in Swift none of which I can get to work. Appears not much on that subject, but I'm looking for a simple example of a SOAP service, can work with REST. Albeit I already have my server side SOAP service built and tested.  For my proof of concept I want to pass one variable and receive back two.

Comment: "Temperature conversion"? Can't you just do this on device?

Comment: Not certain if I understand ' do this on device?'  I was hoping the example temperature conversion webservice would serve as a template, but can't get it to work.  My goal is to retrieve data from DB2 tables via the webservice to populate my iphone app.